# Regex Help for space separated mix of alpha/numeric string

Tags: regex

I have a string like:

```
A B C D
```

where

> A = [0-9]{4}
>
> B = [a-z A-Z]{3,6}
>
> C = [0-9]{1,2,3,4}
>
> D = ([a-z A-Z]{3,6})

I am trying

```
/[0-9]{4} [a-z A-Z]{3,6} [0-9]{1,2,3,4} \([a-z A-Z]{3,6}\)/
```

But it doesn't work.
There's a blank space between AB BC CD

How can this be made to work?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you are trying to match?

Comment: A = 2005 (always a year)

B = SCA or ABCdef

C = 1 23 345 5678

D = (same as B but within brackets)

Comment: I mean add the full strings in the question.

Comment: 2005 SCC 23 (scaLix)

2009 FCT 345 (AsdfEG)

2008 CrAdle 2345 (qWe)

Comment: Why don't you just add spaces between the patterns - `/[0-9]{4}  [a-z A-Z]{3,6}  [0-9]{1,2,3,4}  ([a-z A-Z]{3,6})/`? Also, you need to escape the braces `\(\)`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that:

/[0-9]{4} [a-z A-Z]{3,6} [0-9]{2,3,4} \([a-z A-Z]{3,6}\)/

It doesn't work

Comment: Because you have to escape the brackets: `/[0-9]{4} [a-z A-Z]{3,6} [0-9]{2,3,4} \([a-z A-Z]{3,6}\)/`.

Comment: Yes I had done that.

Here are few actual sting:

2008 TCC 359 (CanLII)

1993 CanLII 34 (SCC) 

1999 CanLII 7552 (FCA)

It doesn't work :(

Comment: Is `_` part of `B` or `D` in any examples ?

Comment: I don't see `space` in `B` and `D` in any of your examples. Please check again if you really want to include `space` in them.

Comment: /[0-9]{4} [a-z A-Z]{3,6} [0-9]{2,3} \([a-z A-Z]{3,6}\)/  Works

/[0-9]{4} [a-z A-Z]{3,6} [0-9]{3,4} \([a-z A-Z]{3,6}\)/ Works

/[0-9]{4} [a-z A-Z]{3,6} [0-9]{2,3,4} \([a-z A-Z]{3,6}\)/ doesn't work

Comment: Could you please check the answer I just posted ? And also answer my doubts regarding your question.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Is this shell, sed, perl, bash, python, C#?

Comment: @rusticnomad A best practice in asking question about regex is adding some input text and expected result. Please add them into you question not just on discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came up with this regex using `shorthand` operators for regex.

**Regex:** `\d{4} \w{3,6} \d{1,4} \(\w{3,6}\)`

**Explanation:**

- `\d` stands for `[0-9]`.
- `\w` stands for `[A-Za-z]`. (In your example there is no space. But your attempt have a `space`. Check that again.)

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF5vT8/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Tried this and this doesn't get matched

2010 FCA 47 (CanLII)

Comment: Instead of a space in the pattern, use `\s` as it matches all Unicode whitespace symbols.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Is it okay to use `\s` when only space is to be matched ? Since `\s` denotes `\r`, `\n`, `\t` too.

Comment: OP says your expression does not match OP's text. That is why I suggest to exclude at least the possibility of a hard space between the string parts. If it works and newlines must not be matched, the regex can further be precised. `[^\S\r\n\v]` matches horizontal whitespace BTW.

Comment: Thanks, it works and only place it fails is \d{1,4} where the number is like 4,765 (ie with a comma). So hot to get this working too ?

Comment: @rusticnomad: Your previous examples didn't had any number with comma `,`. You should know that Regex is specific to the rules. It won't magically match any of the patterns. You should specify the rules correctly before even starting to code.

Comment: @noob -- I am really sorry about that.

Comment: @rusticnomad: So is your problem solved or is there something else remaining ?

Comment: @noob - Yes it is solved. Just used group - (\d{1,4}|\d{1}[,]\d{1,3}) to get the comma issue fixed. This does work now for all four digit numbers, some with , and some without.

The html documents seem to have been done by pasting from word so there were issues of line breaks carrying over. Cleaned it with 

/[\n\r]/, ' '

and then even the pattern matching worked perfect. Earlier some strings were being split to two lines and they were the one's that did not match.

Still struggling with few replaces which isn't behaving the way it should.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @rusticnomad: Well if you lay down the rules of matching then it will be easier to come up with a solution. Know that 90% of the problem in regex is "What you want to match?"  If you are clear about it, rest of the thing boils down to coding.